# Custom header to Opencart Information pages

Tags: opencart

I am trying to create custom information pages in Open Cart, that have specific header. I have done this using this piece of code in header.php

```
if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) 
    || (isset($this->request->get['route']) 
    && ($this->request->get['route'] == 'information/information')))  {
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header_pro.tpl')) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header_pro.tpl';
} else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/common/header_pro.tpl';
}} 

else {
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl';
} else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/common/header.tpl';
}
```

Now what I want to do is chose just several Information pages to which I want to assign header_pro.tpl
Any Ideas how to do that? I have been struggling with this for a while, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you need to check whether the route is `information/information`, it **has to be set** thus you need this only

```php
if (isset($this->request->get['route']) 
    && ($this->request->get['route'] == 'information/information')))  {
```

Now to check also for concrete information pages, just note down their IDs, and add this condition

```php
if (in_array($this->request->get['information_id'], array(1, 2, 3, 45, 49))) {
    // display header_pro.tpl
}
```

so to make it all in once looking like:

```php
if (isset($this->request->get['route']) 
    && $this->request->get['route'] == 'information/information'
    && in_array($this->request->get['information_id'], array(1, 2, 3, 45, 49)))  {
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header_pro.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header_pro.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/common/header_pro.tpl';
    }
} else {
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/common/header.tpl';
    }
}
```